# Test statistic (e.g. chisquare test) inside latex table using the tables-package in R/Knitr/Rstudio

Tags: r, latex, knitr, chi-squared

I would like to use the tabular()-function from the tables-package to do a cross-tabulation of two variables (e.g. v1 and v2), and present the p-value of the chisq-test in the table. It is easy to get the crosstabulation, but I cant get the p-value inside the table. This is what I've been trying, without any luck:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo=TRUE,message=FALSE>>=
library(Hmisc)
library(tables)
v1 <- sample(letters[1:2],200,replace=TRUE)
v2 <- sample(month.name[1:3],200,replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(v1,v2)
@

It is straight forward to get the crosstabulation:
<<results='asis'>>=
latex(   tabular(    Factor(v1)   ~   Factor(v2)      , data=df)  )
@

But I cant get the p-value inside the table:

<<results='asis'>>=
latex(   tabular(    Factor(v1)*chisq.test(v1,v2)$p.value   ~   Factor(v2)      , data=df)  )
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use the [reporttools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reporttools/index.html) package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with `tables::tabular` but this will do it with `Hmisc::summary.formula.reverse` assuming you have your system configured to produce pdf files through latex(). I had to do searching of the Rhelp archives to figure out that the 'exclude1' argument needed to go in the `latex` argument list. Once you go back through the documentation `exclude1` does appear in the usage example of `latex.summary.formula.reverse` although I *thought* I was reading the help page for `summary.rms`:

```
library(Hmisc)
latex(summary( v2 ~ v1, data=df,  method="reverse" ,test=TRUE), exclude1=FALSE)
```

[image]

You can intercept the latex output "along the way" if you want to embed it in a longer document by assigning the output to a named file.

```
latex(summary( v2 ~ v1, data=df,  method="reverse" ,test=TRUE), exclude1=FALSE, file="")
#--------
% latex.default(cstats, title = title, caption = caption, rowlabel = rowlabel,      col.just = col.just, numeric.dollar = FALSE, insert.bottom = legend,      rowname = lab, dcolumn = dcolumn, extracolheads = extracolheads,      extracolsize = Nsize, ...) 
%
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\caption{Descriptive Statistics by v2\label{summary}} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{February}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{January}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{March}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Test Statistic}\tabularnewline
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\scriptsize $N=56$}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\scriptsize $N=73$}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\scriptsize $N=71$}}&\tabularnewline
\hline
v1~:~a&43\%~{\scriptsize~(24)}&47\%~{\scriptsize~(34)}&44\%~{\scriptsize~(31)}&$ \chi^{2}_{2}=0.21 ,~ P=0.901  $\tabularnewline
~~~~b&57\%~{\scriptsize~(32)}&53\%~{\scriptsize~(39)}&56\%~{\scriptsize~(40)}&\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
Numbers after percents are frequencies.\\\noindent Test used:\\Pearson test\end{table}
```

Comment: How do i get it to work with Knitr in Rstudio. When I put this: latex(summary( v2 ~ v1, data=df,  method="reverse" ,test=TRUE), exclude1=FALSE) in an results="asis"-chunk, Rstudio just hangs( by "hangs" i mean that the "stop" sign appears in the lower right corner of the "compile-pdf"-tab, and I need to click stop before I can run other chunks.

Comment: I'm neither an RStudio nor a knitr user, so I am not familiar with the use of "asis"-chunks. You can get "raw" latex output to the console by specifying file="" which might keep the output within the RStudio environment. I'll post the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also paste text from a chi-squared statistic into a caption via xtable(). For example:

```
#sample data
var1<-sample(c('A', 'B'), 10, replace=T)
var2<-sample(c('Red', 'Blue'), 10, replace=T)
#join in frequency table
tab<-table(var1, var2)
#conduct chisq.test
test<-chisq.test(tab)
#show values of chisq.test()
name(test)
#Use xtable, use print.xtable for further manipulations
out<-xtable(tab, caption=paste('Important table, chi-squared =', test$statistic, ', p=', test$p.value,',' ,test$parameter, 'df', sep=' '))
#print
out
```